# PHP SFTP uploaded file was removed automatically

Tags: php, sftp

I am currently uploading files to a third party server through SFTP by using PHP ssh2

The connection are working fine and I tried to upload files using fwrite

```
$resourceId = $this->sftp;
$intResourceId = intval($resourceId);
$dir = "ssh2.sftp://$intResourceId/./".$this->un."/".$file_name; 
$stream = @fopen($dir, 'w');
if (!$stream) {
     return "Could not open file: $file_name";
}

$data_to_send = @file_get_contents(LOCAL_FILE_DIR.$file_name,true);
if ($data_to_send === false){
    return "Could not open local file: $file_name.";
}
if (@fwrite($stream, $data_to_send) === false){
    return "Could not send data from file: $file_name.";
}


/*
readdir():
Array
    (
        [0] => 1810171932.txt
        [1] => response_dir
    )
*/
```

The files were uploaded when I read the directory but after a few seconds it was removed from the directory.

```
/*
readdir():
Array
    (
        [0] => response_dir
    )
*/
```

Any idea why? Does the file being uploaded or there are some permission issue which I need to take care of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the file exists for a second, and then is deleted, it's likely a secondary process that is coming along and cleaning up that directory. (Perhaps it's a script that reads the uploaded files in the folder and removes them)?

Comment: ... and check cron jobs and cpanel configuration

Comment: If you upload a file using a normal SFTP client, do you observe the same behavior?

Comment: @FrankerZ Ya, that is possible, I am checking with the vendor now.

Comment: How "possible"? Try it! That's something you should have tried yourself even before posting a question here.

Comment: Ya! You guys are right. The file was rejected by the vendor. Thanks guys. @MartinPrikryl Ya you are right. But the vendor's documentation doesn't includes the part where they will remove the file if the file is not encrypted. That's why I am curious if there is anything I've missed out